# Trouble scraping all the reviews from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying to fetch all the reviews from a certain page of google maps but my following script can only parse few of them. When I scroll down manually, I can see a spinner while loading the reviews which I've used within the script.

Usually I can reach the bottom of a webpage using `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`.

However, the content are located within the left sided window of that page and that is perhaps the reason the above command is not working.

[Webpage address](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pizzeria+Di+Matteo/@40.8512552,14.255779,17z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf!8m2!3d40.8512512!4d14.2579677!9m1!1b1)

I've tried with (it only parses first few reviews):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pizzeria+Di+Matteo/@40.8512552,14.255779,17z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf!8m2!3d40.8512512!4d14.2579677!9m1!1b1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:  #this block is not working at all
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        wait.until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-loading-spinner']")))
    except Exception:
        break


for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-review-content"))):
    name = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-review-title'] > span"))).text
    review = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-review-text']"))).text
    print(name,review)
```

***How can I scrape all the reviews from that page?***

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script to get all the reviews from that page. In short, when this script finds that spinner, the very next line `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",elem)` scrolls that spinner to the viewport and keeps doing it until there is no content left to be loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pizzeria+Di+Matteo/@40.8512552,14.255779,17z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf!8m2!3d40.8512512!4d14.2579677!9m1!1b1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

while True:
    try:
        elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-loading-spinner']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",elem)
    except Exception:
        break


for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-review-content"))):
    name = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-review-title'] > span"))).text
    review = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-review-text']"))).text
    print(name,review)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionChains and TouchActions

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import TouchActions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pizzeria+Di+Matteo/@40.8512552,14.255779,17z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf!8m2!3d40.8512512!4d14.2579677!9m1!1b1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-review-content")))[-1]
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
touch_actions = TouchActions(driver)
touch_actions.scroll(0, 8000).perform()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-review-content"))):
    name = WebDriverWait(item, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-review-title'] > span"))).text
    review = WebDriverWait(item, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-review-text']"))).text
    print(name, review)
```

Comment: It can scroll few times and then parse the results whereas there are many more. However, it can't exhaust the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get all of the reviews without the browser automation.

You just need the `data_id` (it looks like this: `0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf`, and you can get it from the maps URL you posted)

After that, you just have to make a request to: https://www.google.com/async/reviewDialog?hl=en&async=feature_id:0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf,sort_by:,next_page_token:,associated_topic:,_fmt:pc

There you will find all the reviews data, as well as the `next_page_token`, so you can query the next 10 reviews.

In this case `next_page_token` is: `EgIICg`

So, the request URL for the next 10 reviews would be: https://www.google.com/async/reviewDialog?hl=en&async=feature_id:0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf,sort_by:,next_page_token:EgIICg,associated_topic:,_fmt:pc

You could also use a third party solution like SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all rich structured data for you.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "secret_api_key",
  "engine": "google_maps_reviews",
  "hl": "en",
  "data_id": "0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"place_info": {
  "title": "Pizzeria Di Matteo",
  "address": "Via dei Tribunali, 94, Napoli NA, Italy",
  "rating": 4.4,
  "reviews": 7082
},
"reviews": [
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Thomas Bichler",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/117092186939269423235?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifo9yvmODxAhWHY98KHSDtAakQvvQBegQIARAw",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjDBVeLxUSBqv4WKvPuVqMbpZ5cdDfjyTlcSxTgQKw=s40-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4-br100",
      "local_guide": true,
      "reviews": 164,
      "photos": 88
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "date": "a week ago",
    "snippet": "Great Pizza Fritta! Although the place looks only like a take-away from the outside there is plenty of seating places in the back and upstairs. Don't be afraid to pass by the deep-fryer and make your way to the back. The Pizza Fritta we had easily serves two for lunch. We ordered one per person and couldn't finish it.Nothing fancy here and that's good. Everything is focuessed on the food!",
    "images": [
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipO0xuP-Fbq1R88lr4ecedPcV6I34uIxqW6tro_m=w100-h100-p-n-k-no"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Andrea Caruso",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103428787808835823312?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifo9yvmODxAhWHY98KHSDtAakQvvQBegQIARA_",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgYfhxg1E5DZJJ8YJtjTS5lbhYrQ5ekpbak4VKAtg4=s40-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba5-br100",
      "local_guide": true,
      "reviews": 290,
      "photos": 15
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "date": "6 days ago",
    "snippet": "Classic Italian pizza and one of the best ones!I really liked the Margherita and the melanzane.Slightly disappointed by the sausage in the salsiccia and friarielli.Friendly staff and fast service",
    "images": [
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOw0-2R5bGQ6NVTimGHOOJjUtBvf5phfA0PYtpe=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipM2UUdwNMZnogt2DMptnQsfiFmP_b5mgQPhXlUn=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPaFQYhx5Z2nM0AxDWus52R0xK-5KJP6ZQuEHJU=w100-h100-p-n-k-no"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "asia rizzoli",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106734226225183718730?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifo9yvmODxAhWHY98KHSDtAakQvvQBegQIARBQ",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhiFJr7dFNeo6Y85fCdmMYyaOLl-2YZSPzVTQj83A=s40-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4-br100",
      "local_guide": true,
      "reviews": 69,
      "photos": 111
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "date": "3 weeks ago",
    "snippet": "We tried the ‘frittura’ ‘fried street food’ outside the restaurant entrance. The ‘frittata di pasta’ (fried pasta) was Amazing! I totally fell in love with it. The ‘crocché’ (fried mashed patatos) was also good, although nothing special. We did not like the arancini a lot.. but on a balance it is worth a try!",
    "images": [
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMamXnfHbILMA5y_6v5qHkXjoDM3_i9hwllAwn8=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMwpZ2dqLYnwg2KePI46Qfnk46vDzhXJwCkCjn3=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOwfcwtQIDMUq1M4Qcg54mqrIg1fUWnDZkXfDhr=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipO6I7EgACHnh8UJbfi6H_43m1bPJ4hefqGBn7Zz=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMlLbFU0AaGKkvlLymTX9eTJEDlS881TMvE6Lvk=w100-h100-p-n-k-no",
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNhhzjpiaxCFE4LCAhXGYAT-jz8dsn-S1SDtsWy=w100-h100-p-n-k-no"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-reviews-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*